# Parsing a multiline variable from a file separated by back slash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have an input file like below, its a config file so not a valid shell-script format(format-1):

```
DATA_DB=foo \
        bar \
        zoo
#may be a comment or not(unreliable content)
```

Sometimes, the format(format-2) could be as simple as:

```
DATA_DB=foo1
```

How, can I extract foo, bar, and zoo from this? I tried sourcing `foo.cfg` but it didn't work as the values on RHS are not quoted.

Tried using `while loop -r` but it either work for RHS or LHS.

```
while IFS='=' read -r key val; do echo "$val" ;done < foo.cgf
foo \
```

How to extract `foo` , `bar` and `zoo` from format-1, while the same code should extract `foo1` from format-2?

Comment: Try removing the `-r` from the `read` command.  This may be one of the  exceptions that proves the rule that `read` should always be run with the `-r` option.

Comment: @pjh , this works fine `while IFS='=' read  key val; do if [ "$key" == "DATA_DB" ];then echo "$val";fi ;done < foo1.cfg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    sub(/^DATA_DB=/,"") { f=1 }
    f { if ( sub(/\\$/,"") ) { vals=vals $0 OFS } else { $0=vals $0; $1=$1; print; exit } }
' file
foo bar zoo
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `gnu-grep`, you can do this:

```bash
grep -zoP '(?m)^DATA_DB=\K(?:[^\\\n]+\\\n)*[^\\\n]+\n' file

foo \
        bar \
        zoo
```

Comment: with `grep (GNU grep) 3.1`, returns the empty output.

Comment: Do you have DOS line breaks in your input by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
cat file
DATA_DB=foo \
    bar \
    zoo
#may be a comment or not(unreliable content)

DATA_DB2=foo1

DATA_DB3=bar \
    zoo
```

You can use your loop if you preprocess with a Perl:

```
while IFS='=' read key val; do
    echo "key=$key, val=$val"
done < <(perl -0777 -nE 's/ *\\\R\s*/\t/g; say $& while(/^\w+=.*$/mg);' file)
```

Prints:

```
key=DATA_DB, val=foo    bar zoo
key=DATA_DB2, val=foo1
key=DATA_DB3, val=bar   zoo
```

The multi-value values are now tab separated.

Answer (score 1):

**File**

```
$ cat foo.cfg
#may be a comment or not(unreliable content)
DATA_DB=foo1 \
        bar1 \
        zoo1
#may be a comment or not(unreliable content)
DATA_DB2=foo2 \
        bar2 \
        zoo2
DATA_DB3=foo3
#may be a comment or not(unreliable content)
```

**Script**

```
getKeyValue(){
    local inputfile=$1
    awk '
        /[^#]*=/ { f=1; out=""; }
        f {   
            gsub(/^ */,"",$0); out=out""$0; gsub(/\\/,"",out)
            if(substr($0,length($0),1) != "\\") { f=0; print out }   
        }
    '  $inputfile
}

while IFS='=' read -r key val; do 
    echo "key: $key ==> value: $val"
done < <(getKeyValue foo.cfg)
```

**Output**

```
key: DATA_DB ==> value: foo1 bar1 zoo1
key: DATA_DB2 ==> value: foo2 bar2 zoo2
key: DATA_DB3 ==> value: foo3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -En 's/^([^=]*=|[ \t]+)([^ ]*).*/\2/p' input_file
foo1
foo
bar
zoo
```

Comment: this is also capturing the RHS of any other variable apart from `DATA_DB`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'DATA_DB=foo \
              bar \
              zoo
#may be a comment or not(unreliable content)' |
```

> ```
> mawk NF=NF OFS='\n' FS='[^[:alpha:]]+' \
>            ORS=     RS='^[^=]+=|[[:space:]]*([#][^\n]*\n)?'
> ```

```
foo
bar
zoo%
```

The above approach has the downside of lacking trailing new line. To rectify that, do

> ```
>  gawk 'sub("$",OFS, $!(NF=NF))^_' OFS='\n' FS='[^[:alpha:]]+' ORS= \
>                        RS='^[^=]+[=]|[\\\\[:space:]]+([#][^\n]*\n)?'
> ```

```
foo
bar
zoo
```

Comment: this is also capturing the RHS of any other variable apart from `DATA_DB`

Comment: @monk : if they're never multi-line, then it's much simpler : ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::: :::::::: `echo 'DATA_DB=foo1' | mawk NF=NF FS='^.+=' OFS=` or :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::: `gawk '($!NF = $NF)^_' FS==`  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::`foo1`